# android-maven-plugin: install succeds but compile fails

Tags: maven, android-maven-plugin

I have downloaded

[Morse Flash android-maven-plugin example project](https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/test/projects/morseflash)

However,
I can do mvn install and tests run fine on my device,
but when I do mvn compile I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.4.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project morseflash-instrumentation: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.4.1:generate-sources failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
```

How can install work, but compile fail?

Answer (score 0):

It might have problems with running multiple times. Try to run

```
mvn clean install
```

and if that works

```
mvn clean compile
```

Both should work even if

```
mvn compile
```

fails (it depends what you ran before it)